# What should I use to seal cracks between stone foundation and sill beam?

Tags: foundation, beam, stone, sill

[image: top of foundation wall, between joists]

I'm in the process of replacing subfloor and joist sistering and noticed some pretty serious gaps between the foundation and sill beam after clearing away the loose debris between joists. Would it be advisable to pack hydraulic cement into the gaps? Thanks